# Strange segfault with unique_ptr and shared_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, unique-ptr

I came accross a strange segfault. The cause actually led me to a bug, but I still don't understand why a segmentation fault is caused here... The code is:

```
#include <memory>
int main(int argc, char **arv)
{
    int *i = new int;
    std::unique_ptr<int> u1(i);
    std::unique_ptr<int> u2;
    u1 = std::move(u2); // line 7
    std::shared_ptr<int> s1(i); // line 8
    std::shared_ptr<int> s2;
    s2 = s1;
}
```

I compile with g++ 4.6 and `-std=c++0x` and get a segfault.

If I change line 7 to `u2 = std::move(u1);` (that was the bug) it disappears.
If I change line 8 to `std::shared_ptr<int> s1(new int(3));` (which of course I don't want) it also disappears. If I remove from line 8 on also no segfault.

So no harm done, but I don't understand why there should be a segfault. As far as I understand,
in line 7 an empty pointer is assigned to u1. No reset(), no end of scope. Nevertheless `i` seems to be invalid from there on. Is that intented? That means one has to be very very careful when moving a pointer because another object could be destroyed!

What do you think? How do I protect myself from this?

Thanks, Steffen

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your line 8 is wrong: Once you capture `i` in the `unique_ptr`, you must not again give it to some *other* ownership-taking object! Every owner will attempt to delete `*i`, which is wrong.

Instead, you should create the shared pointer from the *unique* pointer:

```
std::shared_ptr<int> s1(std::move(u2));
```

(Also, you have `u1` and `u2` the wrong way round.)

Comment: what bothers me is that I can do it with not even a warning when compiling with `-pedantic -Wall -Wextra`. Is the answer really just "Don't!"?

Comment: @steffen: Indeed, the answer is "Don't". There's no protection against `int * p = new int; do_crazy_stuff(p); be_insane(p); take_ownership(p);`. The compiler can't really know what you're going to do with the pointer.

Answer (score 4):

This line:

```
u1 = std::move(u2);
```

Makes the previous pointer stored by `u1` to be deleted. Therefore, your `i` pointer gets freed. Creating a `shared_ptr` holding the free'd pointer is undefined behaviour.

Comment: yeah. I figured that. See my comment to Kerrek: no warning whatsoever. The compiler let's my hurt myself here!

Comment: There's nothing wrong with assigning the unique pointers either way.  A default-constructed unique pointer is null, and assignment properly disposes of the old resource. The line `u1 = std::move(u2);` deletes `*i`, and then both `u1` and `u2` are null.

Comment: @KerrekSB I never said there was something wrong with assigning a unique_ptr. The way OP is doing it, the pointer held by `u1` is free'd after move-assigning `u2`. The problem is that he creates a shared_ptr to the(already free'd) pointer. Steffen, the compiler has no ability to know what does shared/unique_ptr do what the pointers they store.

Comment: yeah I guess I overestimated to power of the compiler ;) thanks for putting me on the ground.